# Javascript Regex - Match Sentences and Ignore in-quote Full Stops

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split, match

The regex:

```
(?:(?:Jr|Master|Mr|Ms|Mrs|Dr|Capt|Col|Sgt|Sr|Prof|Rep|Mt|Mount|St|Etc|Eg)\.\s+|["'“(\[]?)(?:\b(?:(?!(?:\S{1,})[.?!]+["']?\s+["']?[A-Z]).)*)(?:(?:(?:Jr|Master|Mr|Ms|Mrs|Dr|Capt|Col|Sgt|Sr|Prof|Rep|Mt|Mount|St|Etc|Eg)\.\s+(?:(?!\w{2,}[.?!]['"]?\s+["']?[A-Z]).)*)?)*(?:(?![.?!]["']?\s+["']?\w).)*(?:[.?!)\]]+["'”]?|[^\r\n]+$)
```

A regex101 can be seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/yfP045/23).

Visualized Node Graph: https://regexper.com (Enter the regex string)

This regex is forked from a Sitepoint discussion, [with an explanation here](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/choose-whole-sentences-and-only-whole-sentences-reliably-with-regex/8075/12).

---

**Aim**: To match sentences not only via .?!, but determining when to do so, such as outside of quotations, but not breaking sentences with abbreviations either.

---

**The main problem**:

There is one major problem, strings like the below are splitting with full stops in the middle when they should not be - I need quotes to remain intact.

> PROBLEM: "This is a problem. You hear me?"

Besides this, is this regex mostly reliable, and efficient?

---

**There may be two other possible problems, or 'exceptions'** (see above regex101):

> Possible problem/exception sentence (Does not properly split due to "Mr."):
> On Feb. 20 Mr. X said "Beyond the fourth wall, there shall be 'light'"?!... Or something. Second sentence. Third.

and

> Possible problem/exception ("Really?" should not split before Capital names?: "Really?" Mr. baker asked, as he proceeded to ponder.

Previous issues I had when I opened this thread, **which I have fixed**, were:

> Text did not split after a single letter followed by a punctuation with a proceeding full stop, before a new sentence. (eg. A.S.A.P! New line.)
>
> Text did not split when a full stop came after a quotation.
>
> Abbreviations at the start of a sentence would break. (eg. Sgt. Timothy.)
>
> New lines without ending punctuation were not matched.

**What do you think about this implementation? Thank you!**

Comment: For any regex to work, the sentences need to always follow a preset number of rules (that you have to determine).  One rule could be something like : a sentence always has a "." at the end.  If the sentences are created by humans and are not validated by does rules, you'll never be able to find a regex pattern that will work.

Comment: An important preset rule is : an abbreviation can not have space in it and it must start with a capital letter.

Comment: This is as you said, regex for sentences created by humans. I understand that rule, however I prefer case insensitivity for errors or oddities. I know I'm stretching this before natural language processing.

Comment: Also another preset rule would have to be : a sentence can not have only one word in it.

Comment: Case insensitivity does not work because there is no way to know the deference between the end of sentence and the end of an abbreviation if you don't know that an abbreviation has started.

Comment: Is there a way to detect for this aside from \w{2}, and still accept abbreviations such as "A.S.A.P!"?

Comment: Again, you have to establish what are the preset rules to know what pattern to construct.  In my opinion "\w{2}" is not good; "\S\." is better, but is it perfect?

Comment: @DominiqueFortin Still new to this. I've replaced \w{2} with only \S (rather than both), which breaks abbreviations. Trying \S{2} fixes some, while \S{4} fixes them all, but continues to break "Sentence Sentence Sentence! Sentence two", probably due to length still. Even if I remove \w with appropriate [A-Za-z] rules. The problem especially with only "\S" is that abbreviations such as "E.T." split after the final full stop, when it shouldn't.

Comment: I suppose the question is, how do I detect an abbreviation such as "E.T." and not stop there?

Comment: "\S{2}" is not good, I said "\S\.".  That's Slash, Letter S uppercase, Slash and a dot.  It's not the same thing.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin "\S\." Does not split paragraph sentences.

Comment: The rule "a sentence always has a '.' at the end" should be : a sentence always has a ".", an "!" or a "?" at the end.

Comment: The "\S\." is to detect an abbreviation.  To detect paragraph you need a rule that tels what a paragraph is made of.  For example : a paragraph is always made of a list of sentence followed be two end of line.

Comment: You can make the pattern for an abbreviation "[A-Z][^?!\S\.]*\." if the rule "a sentence can never have only one word" is always true.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin Where in the existing regex should I be placing this? Thanks.

Comment: If a new line is a sentence terminator, add it to the rules alongside `.!?`

Comment: @Paul S I was actually doing it wrong before, surprisingly it just worked now in 30seconds. Thanks for the push! I do have another problem I may consider, regarding detection of grammar before or after punctuation. Maybe I should reopen the question if I need help with that soon.

Comment: Hi @PaulS. I don't mean to disturb you, but if you have the time, could you review my issue with full stops breaking mid-quote when they shouldn't be? I have updated my OP with an example.

Comment: @user1679669 I would try matching quotes like this `((["'])(?:[^\\]|\\[\s\S])*?\2)`, where valid quote chars are `"` and `'` (although you might want different quote chars to avoid _foo's_ being treated as a quote start). `re.exec('abc "def\' gh\\"i " jkl'); // [""def' gh\"i "", ""def' gh\"i "", """]`. This is coming from the code concept of quotes though. So adapt as required for your case

Comment: @PaulS.I really am out of my depth here, and was not even aware of that. With the example you provide, it does not correctly match sentences such as "Harry, you're a 'wizard'." (it matches 're a ') and with "Sentence 'sentence2'" type sentences. If you could integrate this with my current regex (which currently does not have these two issues), I would be very grateful for your answer! You definitely understand this better than I do. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

try to find sentences with

```
(([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?[,;]?|([A-Z][bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*\.)+[,;]?|[A-Za-z][a-z']*[,;]?)+(\s+|\.|[!?]))+
```

**EDIT:** This is the closest I got.

Comment: This is the result I'm getting: https://regex101.com/r/6XaUil/2

The matches are very sporadic.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt though!